# How to write hibernate template query from the sql query?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

Actually I had one SQL query that runs very fine with `mySql` database. but, my problem is that I want to write that query in `hibernatetemplate` query.

My SQL QUERY IS

```
SELECT * FROM task, dependency WHERE DEPENDENCY_From IN(10,11,12,13)
```

and I want it to executed by the hibernate template.

How do I to convert this to a `HibernateTemplate` Query?

Comment: How are these two tables mapped to entities? What are the association between them? HQL works on entities, not on tables. Without knowing their mapping, it's impossible to answer. Have you read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use `HibernateTemplate` query then below is example of hibernate query but in your case, we need mapping files to see how the entities are associated. Hope below query will help you.

```
public List<Object[]> getCities(Integer stateId)  {
        List<Object[]> cityList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        String query = "select city.cityId,city.cityName from City city where city.state.stateId=?";
        Object[] queryParam = {stateId};
        cityList = getHibernateTemplate().find(query, queryParam);
        return cityList;
    }
```

or

```
String query="from City";
List<City> cityList = getHibernateTemplate().find(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

**HQL query**

```
Object[] params  = {cid,cid};

List list=getHibernateTemplate().find("select S.stateName,C.countryName from State S,Country C where C.countryId=? and S.countryId=?", params);
```

**SQL Query**

```
select S.stateName,C.countryName from State S,Country C where S.countryId=C.countryId;
```