# HQL in HibernateDaoSupport

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

How can I execute this below native query in a DAO class which extends

> org.​springframework.​orm.​hibernate3.​support.HibernateDaoSupport

**Native Query :**

select * from mytable where key="abcd" and id = 111 order by rank asc limit 10 offset 20

**Updated:**

List list =(List) getHibernateTemplate().find(sql);
        return list;

My query was this, here I am not getting the results by according to the conditions

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8612933/4238176

Comment: Do you need a Hibernate query?

Comment: @Akshay Yes that will work

Comment: I have posted the hibernate query that you will need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not put limit and offset in hql.There is a way around.Try the following query,

```
Query query=session.createQuery("from mytable mt WHERE mt.key='abcd' AND mt.id=111 ORDER By mt.rank ASC")
                .setFirstResult(20)
                .setMaxResults(10);
```

In hibernate setFirstResult and setMaxResults are used instead of OFFSET and LIMIT.